# Deleting a record from table in MS ACCESS 2010

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to delete records from the **subreport** that created with multiple tables data.
Below is the code I write for this

```
CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE FROM StateBudget " & " WHERE S_ID=" & ("SLELECT ID FROM States " & " WHERE State=" & Me.subformStateBudget.Form.Recordset.Fields("State"))
```

And error appear like this

> syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'S_ID=SELECT ID
>   FROM States WHERE State=????'.

Comment: As a general rule, don't do = sub-query. Use `IN` instead.

Comment: You can go `DLookUp` as well (`DLookUp("ID", "States",  "State=" & Me.subformStateBudget.Form.Recordset.Fields("State"))` returns exactly the same as your subquery. Access doesn't like it when you refer to more than one table in a delete query. By the way, you are misspelling `SELECT` in your subquery, that might also explain it.

Comment: Thanks for advice, I will fix the misspelling.

Comment: I still face with **Data type mismatch** error when I run with below query
`CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE FROM StateBudget " & " WHERE S_ID = " & DLookup("ID", "States", "State='" & Me.subformStateBudget.Form.Recordset.Fields("State") & "'")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out

```
  CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE FROM StateBudget WHERE S_ID IN (SELECT ID FROM States WHERE State=" & Me.subformStateBudget.Form.Recordset.Fields("State") & ")"
```

And by the way You have got misspelling in select, You add that string wrongly. That Bracket before Select should be inside the string and many more.